# Error in my Scipy Code for Blood Glucose Model

Tags: python, model, scipy, odeint

When I run my code I get some sort of error and I don't know why.

line 233, in odeint
    int(bool(tfirst)))

RuntimeError: The size of the array returned by func (3) does not match the size of y0 (4).

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# define a function containing the derivatives, i.e. the ODE
def glucose(x,t,params):
    X,I, G, Y = x    
    k, alpha, beta, gamma_X, gamma_I, gamma_G, lamda, delta = params
    derivs = [k - gamma_X * X - beta * I * X + lamda * G * Y,
             alpha * X - gamma_I * I,
             delta * Y - gamma_X * G]
    return derivs



k = 5.625 #set value
alpha = 1.111 #the rate of insulin production
delta= 1 #the rate of glucagon production
beta = 0.2 #glycogen produced based on insulin
lamda= 0.1 #glucose produced based on glycogen
gamma_X = 0.25 #glucose used
gamma_I = 1.0 #insulin turnover
gamma_G= 0.5 #glucagon turnover




params = [k, alpha, beta, gamma_X, gamma_I, delta, gamma_G, lamda]



X = 6
I = 5
G= 4 #Glucagon
Y= 5 #Glycagon 
x0 = [X,I,G,Y]




maxt = 12.0
tstep = 0.05

t = np.arange(0,maxt,tstep)

glucose_out = odeint(glucose, x0, t, args=(params,))

plt.plot(t,glucose_out)

plt.legend(['blood glucose', 'insulin level'])
plt.ylabel('Blood Glucose Level mmol/L , Blood Insulin 10pmol/L')
plt.xlabel('Time/h')
plt.title('Glucose-Insulin Regulation Model')
```

How do I get rid of the error to produce a graph?

Comment: It appears that your system has four components (X, I G and Y).  So your function `glucose(x, t, params)` must return four derivatives (dX/dt, dI/dt, dG/dt and dY/dt).  Currently it returns only three.

Comment: Include the missing derivative in the return value of `glucose(x, t, params)`.